# Rails query related tables column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/) you can create queries that span relationships

`Entry.objects.filter(blog__name='Beatles Blog')`

What is the rails equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails approach is not as clean, but it allows you to be explicit in your query.
In a situation as described above, you would do

```
Entry.joins(:blog).where(blogs: {name: "Beatles Blog"})
```

This is assuming your Blog `has_many :entries` and your Entry `belongs_to :blog`

Also note that you still have access to a kind of SQL interface for this, however, you should always ensure to `joins|includes|eager_load` the associations that you would be querying, the way I joined the `blog` above.

```
Entry.joins(:blog).where("blogs.name = ?", "Beatles Blog")
```

OR using named parameters

```
Entry.joins(:blog).where("blogs.name = :blog_name", blog_name: "Beatles Blog")
```

Hope I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help for you.

```
Entry.where(blog__name: "Beatles Blog")
```

assuming that blog__name is column name